# MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljxl.Cell;.getLastCellNum() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Tags: groovy, soapui, missingmethodexception

I'm new to groovy and I'm trying to drive data from excel in soapUI using hashmap concept, but I'm getting an error :

> MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljxl.Cell;.getLastCellNum() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

How do I get the value of last cell in a row in groovy?

Here is my code:

```
public static Map<String,String> getTestDataMap(int keyRowNumber,int valueRowNumber){
    Map<String,String> testData=new HashMap<String, String>();

    FileInputStream excelFile;
    try {

        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File('C:/Users/aparnam/Desktop/AmazonTestData.xls'))
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Queries")
        def headerRow = sheet.getRow(keyRowNumber);

        for(int i=0;i<headerRow.getLastCellNum();i++){
            testData.put(sheet.getRow(keyRowNumber).getCell(i).toString(), sheet.getRow(valueRowNumber).getCell(i).toString());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Test Data file Not found"+e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("unable to read excel file"+e.getMessage());
    }
    return testData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mix `org.apache.poi` and `jxl` libraries for reading excel file. Check your imports. In `jxl` that you use there is no method `getLastCellNum()` and `sheet.getRow()` returns array of cells.
[Sheet API doc](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html). Maybe appropriate for you will be use something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<headerRow.getColumns();i++){
    testData.put(sheet.getRow(keyRowNumber)[i].toString(), sheet.getRow(valueRowNumber)[i].toString());
}
```